# Which is faster ?Multiple Conditions in one IF statement or switch case with multiple IF statements

Tags: javascript, performance, if-statement, switch-statement, coding-efficiency

I came to a point where I needed to check a condition and proceed with another condition if its true for many times.

Here I'm using `fromNS` string which has the base of number (like - binary, decimal, octal) and then a condition to check if the
`fromValue` is a valid number using regex.

If the value is invalid as per the base then `displayError()` function is called.

```
from.addEventListener("input", function () {
   fromValue = from.value;

   // Is this method efficient
   if((fromNS == "Binary"      && !/^[01]*$/.test(fromValue))        ||
      (fromNS == "Decimal"     && !/^[0-9]*$/.test(fromValue))       ||
      (fromNS == "Hexadecimal" && !/^[0-9a-fA-F]*$/.test(fromValue)) ||
      (fromNS == "Octal"       && !/^[0-7]*$/.test(fromValue)))
      displayError();


   // Or should I use this 
   switch (fromNS) {
      case "Binary":
         if(!/^[01]*$/.test(fromValue)) displayError();
      break;
      case "Decimal":
         if(!/^[0-9]*$/.test(fromValue)) displayError();
      break;
      case "Hexadecimal":
         if(!/^[0-9a-fA-F]*$/.test(fromValue)) displayError();
      break;
      case "Octal":
         if(!/^[0-7]*$/.test(fromValue)) displayError();
      break;
   }
});
```

Comment: The `switch` is probably better.

Comment: the switch is easier to understand and would allow you to add a modifier in display error to provide more context on the error.  I doubt speed is a real concern all things considered

Comment: Thank you so much. I was wondering if there is any difference in processing time.

Comment: If you don't call this function thousand times a second, performance doesn't matter here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with one of these:

```
const conditions = [
  formNS === "Binary" && !/^[01]*$/.test(form.value),
  formNS === "Decimal" && !/^[0-9]*$/.test(form.value),
  formNS === "Hexadecimal" && !/^[0-9a-fA-F]*$/.test(form.value),
  formNS === "Octal" && !/^[0-7]*$/.test(form.value),
];

if (conditions.some(Boolean) {
  displayError();
}
```

```
const conditions = [
  { ns: "Binary", regex: /^[01]*$/ },
  { ns: "Decimal", regex: /^[0-9]*$/ },
  { ns: "Hexadecimal", regex: /^[0-9a-fA-F]*$/ },
  { ns: "Octal", regex: /^[0-7]*$/ },
];

if (conditions.some(({ ns, value }) => formNS === ns && !value.match(regex))) {
  displayError();
}
```

```
switch (true) {
  case formNS === "Binary" && !/^[01]*$/.test(form.value):
  case formNS === "Decimal" && !/^[0-9]*$/.test(form.value):
  case formNS === "Hexadecimal" && !/^[0-9a-fA-F]*$/.test(form.value):
  case formNS === "Octal" && !/^[0-7]*$/.test(form.value):
    displayError();
}
```